# Based on the selection of a combobox how do I make a selection from a combobox excel 2010 go to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Based on the selection of a combobox how do I make a selection from a combobox excel 2010 go to another worksheet? For example, i have a combobox with all the monthes in it and based on January I want the information to go to January. If I select February I want the information on the userform to go to the worksheet February and so an. I want to acheive this through a submit button (Command_button) on the userform. any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
       Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ssheet As Workbook
Dim cellVal1 As String, cellVal2 As String, cellVal3 As String, cellVal4 As String, cellVal5 As String, cellVal6 As String, cellVal7 As String, cellVal8 As String, cellVal9 As String, cellVal10 As String, cellVal11 As String, cellVal12 As String
Dim cellVal13 As String, cellVal14 As String, cellVal15 As String, cellVal16 As String, cellVal17 As String, cellVal18 As String, cellVal19 As String, cellVal20 As String, cellVal21 As String, cellVal22 As String
Dim cellVal23 As String, cellVal24 As String, cellVal25 As String, cellVal26 As String, cellVal27 As String, cellVal28 As String, cellVal29 As String, cellVal30 As String, cellVal31 As String, cellVal32 As String, cellVal33 As String, cellVal34 As String

Dim shtCmb As String
Dim RwLast As Long

shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value
If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

cellVal1 = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
cellVal2 = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
cellVal3 = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
cellVal4 = Me.TextBox31.Text
cellVal5 = Me.TextBox1.Text
cellVal6 = Me.TextBox2.Text
cellVal7 = Me.TextBox3.Text
cellVal8 = Me.TextBox4.Text
cellVal9 = Me.TextBox5.Text
cellVal10 = Me.TextBox6.Text
cellVal11 = Me.TextBox7.Text
cellVal12 = Me.TextBox8.Text
cellVal13 = Me.TextBox9.Text
cellVal14 = Me.TextBox10.Text
cellVal15 = Me.TextBox11.Text
cellVal16 = Me.TextBox12.Text
cellVal17 = Me.TextBox13.Text
cellVal18 = Me.TextBox14.Text
cellVal19 = Me.TextBox15.Text
cellVal20 = Me.TextBox16.Text
cellVal21 = Me.TextBox17.Text
cellVal22 = Me.TextBox18.Text
cellVal23 = Me.TextBox19.Text
cellVal24 = Me.TextBox20.Text
cellVal25 = Me.TextBox21.Text
cellVal26 = Me.TextBox22.Text
cellVal27 = Me.TextBox23.Text
cellVal28 = Me.TextBox24.Text
cellVal29 = Me.TextBox25.Text
cellVal30 = Me.TextBox26.Text
cellVal31 = Me.TextBox27.Text
cellVal32 = Me.TextBox28.Text
cellVal33 = Me.TextBox29.Text
cellVal34 = Me.TextBox30.Text

RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AJ" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal2
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("A" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal3
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AH" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal4
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal5
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("C" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal6
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("D" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal7
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("E" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal8
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("F" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal9
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("G" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal10
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("H" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal11
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("I" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal12
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("J" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal13
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("K" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal14
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("L" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal15
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("M" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal16
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("N" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal17
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("O" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal18
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("P" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal19
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Q" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal20
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("R" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal21
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("S" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal22
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("T" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal23
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("U" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal24
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("V" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal25
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("W" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal26
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("X" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal27
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Y" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal28
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Z" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal29
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AA" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal30
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AB" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal31
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AC" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal32
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AD" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal33
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AF" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal34

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub optionCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant

    ' MonthName(Month(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Month
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = MonthName(month(Now)) Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem1
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = MonthName(month(Now))
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem2
        For Each Entry In [List2]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem3
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post your code so we can hel pyou with it.  If you dont have any code then give it a shot(best bet is to use the macro recorder) and post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a 3 sheets : Jan, Feb, Mar.

Created a User Form :

[image]

On the Activate Event of the Userform, add the Months to the Combo Box. The code for it is :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    
With Me.ComboBox1    
.AddItem "Jan"    
.AddItem "Feb"    
.AddItem "Mar"    
.AddItem "Apr"    
.AddItem "May"    
End With    
End Sub
```

Event on Submit button click :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
Dim month As String    
month = Me.ComboBox1.Value    
Select Case month    
Case "Jan"       
 Sheets("Jan").Activate    
Case "Feb"       
 Sheets("Feb").Activate    
Case "Mar"        
Sheets("Mar").Activate    
End Select    
End Sub
```

Now run the form and try it. Thank You.

Comment: I posted all the correct code up top. It works great! Thanks for your help!